# VBA WorksheetFunction

Tags: excel, vba

I have these entries in my VBA instead of using WorksheetFunction as I couldn't work out how to get it to work...

If possible, I would love to have at least the first two lines replaced with WorksheetFunction. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
Application.Goto Reference:="'Handling Units'!HUNUM01"

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR((WHNUMB&REPT(0,14-LEN(STARTNUMB))&STARTNUMB+(RC[-1]-1)),"""")"

Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B5:B" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure **every** object that is located in a worksheet (like `Range`, `Cells`, `Rows`, `Columns` etc) are referenced to a worksheet!

Therefore using `Worksheets("Handling Units").Range("HUNUM01")` is more straight forward than using `Range("'Handling Units'!HUNUM01")`. In your code the ranges in `Destination:= Range("B5:B" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)` have no sheet specified so this code might fail if `Handling Units` is not the active sheet. To avoid this specify a worksheet for all objects located in a worksheet. Do not let Excel guess, it might guess wrong!

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Handling Units")
    .Range("HUNUM01").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR((WHNUMB&REPT(0,14-LEN(STARTNUMB))&STARTNUMB+(RC[-1]-1)),"""")"
    .Range("HUNUM01").AutoFill Destination:= .Range("B5:B" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
End With
```

*Note that the leading dot in* `.Range` *makes this* `Range` *using the worksheet of the* `With` *statemant. Make sure it is there otherwise it does **NOT** use the* `With` *statement even if it is inside the* `With` *block.*

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just going with this, seems simple enough and more effective than what I had before.

```
Range("'Handling Units'!HUNUM01").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR((WHNUMB&REPT(0,14-LEN(STARTNUMB))&STARTNUMB+(RC[-1]-1)),"""")"
Range("'Handling Units'!HUNUM01").AutoFill Destination:= Range("B5:B" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

Comment: Note that the `Range` and `Rows` objects in your `Destination:=` have no sheet specified and therefore this code might fail when `Handling Units` is not the active sheet. See my answer how to avoid that.